# Resolving java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener exception in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring. I created a simple application using springMVC where, on first hit to the application, based on the welcome file list, the user is directed to login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
           <img alt="header image" src="header.jpg" style="width:1350px;height:150px"/>
        </div>
        <div id="content" style="height:300px">
                <div id="login_box" style="background-color: rgb(206, 236, 245); height: 200px; width: 400px; margin-left: 360px; margin-top: 57px;">

                    <div style="padding-left: 45%; border-top-width: 0px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 15px;">Login</div>
                    <div>
                      <form action="/hbfcbank/home.htm">
                            <table style="padding-left: 70px;">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Login Id : </td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="logiId"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Password : </td>
                                        <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>

                            </table>
                            <div style="padding-left: 150px; padding-top: 25px;">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="submit"/>
                            </div>

                      </form>
                    </div>
                </div>      
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <img alt="footer image" src="footer.jpg" style="width:1350px;height:50px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On clicking the submit button on the login.jsp,it should redirect to the home page home.jsp for which I have added the springmvc configuration in web.xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>HBFC bank</display-name>
    <description>
        This is a simple web application with a source code organization
        based on the recommendations of the Application Developer's Guide.
    </description>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/jsp/login.jsp</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

And Below is the springapp-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

  <!-- the application context definition for the springapp DispatcherServlet -->

  <bean name="/home.htm" class="com.hbfcbank.controller.LoginController"/>

</beans>
```

and the LoginController is below

```
package com.hdfcbank.controller;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

public class LoginController implements Controller {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0,
            HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("in LoginController");
        return new ModelAndView("/jsp/home.jsp");
    }

}
```

Still After hitting the submit button on login.jsp, I am getting the following error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:461)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please provide cause of the error and solution for the same.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener
```

means that you don't have that class in the CLASSPATH. It is located in the `spring-context` jar.

So, there is just need to place it to the CLASSPATH, e.g. `WEB-INF/lib` or even better there where is `spring-webmvc`. Because exactly the last one requires `ApplicationListener` for its classes.

From other side using some dependency management tool, like Maven or Gradle, you aren't faced similar issue because `spring-context` is transitive dependency from `spring-webmvc` or its parent - `spring-web`.

Comment: Thanks Artem. Actually I had only two jars initially. I added all jars required for spring(core, expression, beans, aop, alliance,commons-logging etc  and not just only springwebmvc jar.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for duplicate import jar. Check for the presence of two packages ApplicationListener class, delete one, try again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree with Artem Bilan.And If your are using Maven, Please make sure u have added Maven Dependency in your Dependency Assembly Setting.